# removing rows only if it's returned by another query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables

```
CREATE TABLE message_log
(
  id integer,
  message text,
  from_id character varying(500),
  to_id character varying(500),
  match_id character varying(500),
  own_account boolean,
  reply_batch boolean DEFAULT false,
  insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
)


CREATE TABLE likes
(
  id integer,
  userid character varying(500),
  insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
)
```

I have the following query which returns match_ids if no message with the same `match_id` is sent that contains "@".

```
select distinct(match_id) from message_log where own_account = TRUE and match_id not in 
(select match_id from message_log where message like '%@%')
```

I want to also return the to_ids because they are needed in the query I want to construct so I modified the query to

```
select distinct(match_id, to_id) from message_log where own_account = TRUE and match_id not in 
(select match_id from message_log where message like '%@%')
```

Now I want to create a query that would delete any row in the likes table if the `to_id` returned from the above query matches the `userid` in the likes table. Is it possible to do this in one query?

Comment: `delete from ... where to_id in (select ...)`. But `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. Don't put column lists - in parentheses in Postgres it does not what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
delete from b
from (
    select distinct match_id, to_id
    from message_log
    where own_account = TRUE and match_id not in (select match_id from message_log where message like '%@%')
) a inner join likes b on a.to_id = b.userid
```

Essentially, just take your results, and inner join on your likes table to determine what results to delete from the likes table.